# Plotting an irregularly-spaced RGB image in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot several RGB images on one set of axes with matplotlib.  I initially tried using imshow for this, but it doesn't seem to handle two images on one set of axes with different extents (when I plot the second, it makes the first disappear).  I think the answer here is to use pcolormesh, like in [How to plot an irregular spaced RGB image using python and basemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222733/how-to-plot-an-irregular-spaced-rgb-image-using-python-and-basemap)

However, this doesn't seem to work for me - the color coming from the mappable (i.e. the data array I pass to pcolormesh, and the cmap I specify) overrides the face color I specify.  The edges of the grid do have the right color, but not the faces.

Does anyone know how to set the color of the *faces* directly? Ideally I'd use a pcolormesh that takes an n*m*3 array as an alternative to n*m, just like imshow...

A minimal example of how I'd like it to work:
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
#make some sample data
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,255,1),np.linspace(0,255,1))
r, g = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,255,100),np.linspace(0,255,120))
b=255-r

#this is now an RGB array, 100x100x3 that I want to display
rgb = np.array([r,g,b]).T

m = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, rgb/255.0, linewidth=0)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the call to plt.pcolormesh fails, with

```
numRows, numCols = C.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I guess this is because it wants a 2D array, not a 3D array with the last dimension being 3 long.

Comment: That is how pcolor mesh should work....  Can you include a minimal (runnable) example of what you have tried?

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks.  That was the first thing I tried (I've added an example above) but it didn't work, the error strongly suggested it was assuming a 2D array as input.  I'm using matplotlib 1.3.1 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 9):

The solution was very simple: the one thing I needed to do that wasn't in the question I linked to was to **remove the array** from the mesh object.  A minimal example, in case it's helpful to others:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#make some sample data
r, g = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,255,100),np.linspace(0,255,100))
b=255-r

#this is now an RGB array, 100x100x3 that I want to display
rgb = np.array([r,g,b]).T

color_tuple = rgb.transpose((1,0,2)).reshape((rgb.shape[0]*rgb.shape[1],rgb.shape[2]))/255.0

m = plt.pcolormesh(r, color=color_tuple, linewidth=0)
m.set_array(None)
plt.show()
```

I guess the color_tuple line might be non-obvious: essentially we need to turn the (n, m, 3) array into an (n*m, 3) array.  I think the transpose is necessary to get everything to match up correctly.  It's also worth noting that the colors we pass in need to be floating-point, between 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you add an issue on gh about this?

Comment: Issue here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4277 so others can see when this workaround is no longer necessary.

Comment: This only seems to work when passing `r`, and not `r, g`... So we're only using the shape of `r` and not its actual values anymore?

Comment: This method almost solved my problem. The color_tuple don't put the colors in the right order. My image looks scrabbled.

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389335/how-to-plot-geolocated-rgb-data-faster-using-python-basemap shows that you need to index the RGB array with one less column in order to get the array right: rgb[:, :-1, :]. Doing this caused my image to not be scrambled.

Answer (score -3):

How about combining all your images into one big numpy array which you then display with imshow?

Comment: That's certainly one option, but the pixels in my images don't necessarily match up (e.g. they are rotated relative to one another).  Of course I could rotate/scale/resample them as necessary, but that feels like I'm reimplementing a lot of features that pcolormesh gives me for free with monochrome images.  I'm fairly sure that resampling/combining myself then using imshow would be faster, though.