# RGB polar plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, imshow, polar-coordinates

I am trying to produce RGB polar plots in Python and I was expecting `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to be able to do it. However, whenever I try plotting data using this method I obtain a blank output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]],[[0,0,0.5],[0,0.5,0],[0.5,0,0]]])
# Sample, any N,M,3 data should work
ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.imshow(data,extent=[0,2*np.pi,0,1]) # Produces a white circle
```

Is there a good way to accomplish this using the aforementioned method or another ?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I managed to make a single quadrant by using `extent=[0,np.pi/2,0,1]` but its use is clearly bugged for polar plots. since anything but a full quadrant doesn't produce the expected outcome.

Comment: If you haven't looked already, Here are some demo colored polar plots that may be adapted to your needs: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html

Comment: Anil_M yes I've looked, but none of theses are RGB polar plots, simply polar plots with a colorbar. I want to plot a [N,M,3] array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `imshow` on a polar plot is unfortunately not possible, because the imshow grid is necessarily quadratic in its pixels. You may however use `pcolormesh` and apply a trick (similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232439/plotting-an-irregularly-spaced-rgb-image-in-python)), namely to provide the colors as `color` argument to `pcolormesh`, as it would usually just take 2D input.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]],
                 [[0,0,0.5],[0,0.5,0],[0.5,0,0]]])

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

#get coordinates:
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,data.shape[1]+1)
r = np.linspace(0,1,data.shape[0]+1)
Phi,R = np.meshgrid(phi, r)
# get color
color = data.reshape((data.shape[0]*data.shape[1],data.shape[2]))

# plot colormesh with Phi, R as coordinates, 
# and some 2D array of the same shape as the image, except the last dimension
# provide colors as `color` argument
m = plt.pcolormesh(Phi,R,data[:,:,0], color=color, linewidth=0)
# This is necessary to let the `color` argument determine the color
m.set_array(None)


plt.show()
```

[image]

The result is not a circle because you do not have enough points. Repeating the data, `data = np.repeat(data, 25, axis=1)` would then allow to get a circle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks! set_array(None) was exactly what I needed. For some reason the "color" kwarg only overwrites the edge color by default. It's strange that we need to use a sort of dummy 2D color variable and then overwrite it.