# How to pcolormesh RGBA array with 2D x and y?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a RGBA array (`img`) with 2D x and y like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(100)

x = np.arange(10, 20)
y = np.arange(0, 10)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(10, 10, 4))
```

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401623/), we can pass any array to plot and set the color using `img`:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.pcolormesh(x, y, img[:, :,0], color=img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1]), 4)/255)
```

However, it just changed the edgecolors.

[image: edge_color]

I want to show it like `axs.imshow(img)`

[image: imshow]

Comment: I don’t think you can specify rgba with pcolormesh. Is there a reason you don’t want to use imshow?  Perhaps consider using the extent kwargs. .

Comment: @JodyKlymak It seems the extent for `imshow` only supports `xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax`. If the space of x and y isn't equal, it will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: here is the completed example code given [the trick you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630831/7347925) to impede the assignment of the colormapped colors.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(100)

x = np.arange(10, 21)
y = np.arange(0, 11)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(10, 10, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, img[:, :,0], facecolors=img.reshape(-1, 4)/255)
# This is necessary to let the `color` argument determine the color
mesh.set_array(None)
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh with changed colors]

PS: Also note that `img.reshape(-1, 4)` is a shortcut (and more maintainable) version of `img.reshape(img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], 4)`.

Also note that the `x` and `y` refer to the borders between the cells, and there need to be one value more than the number of cells in each dimension. Therefore, I incremented `np.arange(10, 20)` to `np.arange(10, 21)`, but if you want `10..19` as centers, you need to subtract `0.5` for the position of the border (as e.g. `np.arange(10, 21) - 0.5`).

As commented by Jody Klymak, it's recommended not to use `color` which refers to both `facecolor` and `edgecolor`. As the edges are overlapping with their neighbors, some strange effects are visible when transparency comes into play.

Comment: @JohanC Strange. What's the version of your matplotlib? It doesn't work for 3.5.0 which still shows the viridis color. Or do I have to use some specific backend of matplotlib?

Comment: I'm running in an interactive PyCharm environment with matplotlib 3.4.3

Comment: Thanks. I have tested the same version with Qt5Agg and TkAgg in Linux terminal. I still got the viridis image ... @JodyKlymak any idea?

Comment: I find another method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630831/7347925). `m.set_array(None)` can show the correct image.

Comment: This definitely works.  Future readers should be aware that this seems to be undefined behaviour though, and could change in future versions.  Probably the best bet is to open a feature request on GitHub to have a proper API for this.

Comment: As of 3.7 this workaround is no longer needed.  See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950850/3394386)

Answer (score 2):

Since Matplotlib v3.7, the RGB(A) array can be passed directly.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#pcolormesh-accepts-rgb-a-colors

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(100)

x = np.arange(10, 20)
y = np.arange(0, 10)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(10, 10, 4)) / 255

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.pcolormesh(x, y, img)
plt.show()
```

Edit: note I converted the `img` array to float, as the original array gave me

```
ValueError: Image RGB array must be uint8 or floating point; found int64
```

[image]